# Ext JS 5.1 won't load use appfolder path to find js

Tags: extjs, scheduler

I am trying to clean up and restructure my javascript in my app, but once I change it it stops working. I am using ext scheduler in my app so that might be the problem. Here is how I want to set up

```
/ext/scheduler-3.0.0(all core code for schedule components go here)
/ext-all.js
/myscheduler(custom code for schedule components go here)
--/global/
----/view/
------globalscheduling.js
    /model/
```

And This is how I start my app

```
    ExtLatest.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
    ExtLatest.define("scheduler.Application", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Application",
    requires: ["myscheduler.global.view.globalschedulegrid"],
    name: "scheduler",
    appFolder: "",
    launch: function () {
        getData()
    }
});
```

However extjs still trying to go to https://c.na17.visual.force.com/apex/myscheduler/global/view/globalschedulegrid.js to find my view file what I doing wrong here?

Comment: I specified appFolder to be like this.                                                appFolder: "https://c.na17.visual.force.com/resource/1431013342000/ConnectWeb/scripts/libs/myscheduler"

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('myscheduler.global.view.globalschedulegrid', 'path to my scheduler');
```

OR

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    paths: {
        'myscheduler': 'myscheduler',
    }
});
```

[Link to 5.0 Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-setPath) (Not sure which version you are using but it's the same)

Answer (score 0):

5.1 as noted in the title. I didn't have to set the path for globalschedulegrid. Just specifying the paths in setConfig like this

```
ExtLatest.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true, 
        paths: {
            'scheduler': "{!URLFOR($Resource.ConnectWeb, 'scripts/libs/scheduler')}"
        }
    });
```